# Get Outlook addressbook from Azure AD

Tags: outlook, azure-active-directory, exchange-server, azure-ad-graph-api

I need to implement addressbook in my web application. Client would like to see all email addresses he sees when he's composing e-mail with Outlook. I wonder if this is at all possible? They have Azure AD but does it store this data? If it does, what MS Graph endpoints should I call?

Comment: You can use graph api: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=mail` to get all of the email addresses of AD users.

Comment: I thought of doing this. But doesn't Outlook addressbook also suggest external e-mails that you used in the past? This would only show e-mails of company employees?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all email address that a user has used before, you can just get this user's all emails to extract senders and receivers, try the API below to do this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user object ID>/messages?$filter=sentDateTime ge 2021-04-14T00:00:00Z&$select =sender,toRecipients,ccRecipients,bccRecipients
```

You can specify `sentDateTime` based on your requirement, in this case, I list all emails within a month. You will need to do some extra work based on the result, for instance, adding them into a list and remove all duplicated emails.

You can find user `object id` and `User Principal Name` on Azure Portal => Azure Active Directory=> Users=> Profile:

[image]

Comment: I will not be working in context of logged in user, but application context. So I don't know what /me endpoint would return in this case.

Comment: @PiotrPerak, if so use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user object ID>` I have updated my answer

Comment: What would be user object ID in this case?

Comment: @PiotrPerak, object id is a user's unique identifier in Azure AD.  `object ID` or `User Principal Name`  both works here, you can use one of them. I have appended the acpture about them on Azure Portal.

Comment: So I need them to login using their Azure AD into my app, otherwise I won't have this object ID. Currently they are using local accounts in my application.

Comment: @PiotrPerak, exactly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I'm still missing something. This endpoint would return anything only after I send any message. But I think Outlook will suggest company e-mails after I first open it.

Comment: @PiotrPerak If you want to get company e-mails, just call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=mail`

Comment: As mentioned, all the employee email addresses (and aliases) are retrievable via the /v1.0/users endpoint.  Using the /v1.0/users/<upn>/messages endpoint to retrieve all the addresses a person mailed to in order to make a list seems like a bad idea.  For one it could be slow due to a ton of messages and secondarily, from an Application scoped permissions standpoint, they would have to grant you Read access to every mailbox in the company.